# Iterating over array of Ruby Hashes and counting the no. of times value has appeared?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, hash

I have a Ruby array of Hashes with structure

```
[{:fruit=>"apple"}, {:fruit=>"apple"}, {:fruit=>"apple"}, {:fruit=>"banana"}, {:fruit=>"banana"}, {:fruit=>"pineapple"}].
```

I want a final hash which will be:

```
{:apple => 3,:banana=> 2,:pineapple=>1}
```

How to accomplish this?

Comment: Have you tried to write some code to perform the task?

Answer (score 2):

Create an Hash with a default value and iterate over each hash in the array:

```
fruits = [{:fruit=>"apple"}, {:fruit=>"apple"}, {:fruit=>"apple"}, {:fruit=>"banana"}, {:fruit=>"banana"}, {:fruit=>"pineapple"}]
h = Hash.new(0)
fruits.each { |item| h[item[:fruit]] += 1 }
```

Answer (score 2):

The usual trick for computing a histogram such as this, is to use `Enumerable#group_by` and then `Enumerable#map` the resulting `Array`s to their `size`s, and lastly convert to a `Hash`:

```
ary = [{ fruit: 'apple' }, { fruit: 'apple' }, { fruit: 'apple' }, 
  { fruit: 'banana' }, { fruit: 'banana' }, { fruit: 'pineapple' }]

ary.
  group_by {|h| h.values.first }.
  map {|fruit, ary| [fruit.to_sym, ary.size]}.
  to_h
# => { apple: 3, banana: 2, pineapple: 1 }
```

But there is a better way: a datastructure called a `MultiSet` does exactly what you want. Unfortunately, there isn't one in the Ruby core library or stdlib, but you can find some implementations floating around:

```
Multiset[*ary.map {|el| el.values.first.to_sym}]
# => #<Multiset:#3 :apple, #2 :banana, #1 :pineapple>
```

However, almost always when you have a datastructure such as an array of hashes of symbols to strings or something like that, there is an object in there wanting to come out. After all, Ruby is an object-oriented language, not an array-of-hashes-of-symbols-to-strings-oriented language.

```
class Fruit
  attr_reader :name

  def ==(other)
    name == other.name
  end

  def eql?(other)
    name.eql?(other.name)
  end

  def hash
    name.hash
  end

  def to_s
    name
  end

  def inspect
    "#<Fruit: #{name}>"
  end

  private

  attr_writer :name

  def initialize(name)
    self.name = name
  end
end

Multiset[Fruit.new('apple'), Fruit.new('apple'), Fruit.new('apple'), 
  Fruit.new('banana'), Fruit.new('banana'), Fruit.new('pineapple')]
# => #<Multiset:#3 #<Fruit: apple>, #2 #<Fruit: banana>, #1 #<Fruit: pineapple>>
```

Answer (score 2):

@Simone has it right, you can use the inject method to count occurrences, like so:

```
[23] pry(main)> arr
=> [{:fruit=>"apple"}, {:fruit=>"apple"}, {:fruit=>"apple"}, {:fruit=>"banana"}, {:fruit=>"banana"}, {:fruit=>"pineapple"}]
[24] pry(main)> arr.inject({}) { |sum, val| sum[val[:fruit]] = sum[val[:fruit]].to_i + 1; sum }
=> {"apple"=>3, "banana"=>2, "pineapple"=>1}
```

This isn't crystal clear from the code but the reason you need to call `.to_i` on the hash is because if it returns nil (ie the first time it comes across "apple"), you can't do `nil + 1`, so instead `nil.to_i` becomes zero.  I don't think that's super legible from the code above so I thought I'd mention it.

Though mine is a "solution", Jorg has it right when it comes to best practices, this would be a good opportunity to look at an OO solution.

Answer (score 1):

input = [{:fruit=>"apple"}, {:fruit=>"apple"}, {:fruit=>"apple"}, {:fruit=>"banana"}, {:fruit=>"banana"}, {:fruit=>"pineapple"}]

```
output = {}
input.each do |item|
  output[item[:fruit]] = 0 unless output[item[:fruit]]
  output[item[:fruit]] += 1
end
p output
```